# Get Data From Mysql_Fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

I have table, its name is "PBK", in pbk tables theres
1. ID
2. Group ID
3. Name
4. Number
5. NPP

I have value from NPP and check into PBK tables, I want to get "Number" Values from PBK tables and insert that number to "Outbox". i can't to get Number values i used MYSQL_FETCH_ARRAY

this is my code,

```
  $npp2 = $data->val($i,2);
  $npp = $upper = strtoupper($npp2);
  $sql = "SELECT id FROM pbk WHERE NPP = '$npp'";
  $ada=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
  if(mysql_num_rows($ada)>0)
  { 
  $row= mysql_fetch_array($ada,mysqli_assoc);
  $kirim_pesan = mysql_query("insert into outbox (DestinationNumber,TextDecoded, CreatorID)
  values('".$row['Number']."', '$pesan', 'Gammu')");
  }
```

I hove you can help me, thanks for your help.

Comment: Make sure you use mysql or mysqli

Comment: saya sudah coba mas anto ubah mysql atau mysqli sama aja gak berhasil itu kenapa ya mas? bisa bantu mas?

Comment: mysql is deprecated use mysqli or PDO...

Comment: pretty sure this needs to be all caps `mysqli_assoc`, other then that I would avoid mysql_ functions as they are removed in PHP7+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments the constant

```
mysqli_assoc
```

Needs to be all caps

```
MYSQL_ASSOC
```

That and your mixing mysql and mysqli, `mysql` is deprecated and will be removed in PHP7+ so I would avoid using it.

What you have happening though is this `mysqli_assoc` will issue a warning, which if you had error reporting on you would know, then PHP will convert it to a string because it does not exist as a constant. Constants are case sensitive.  And when they don't exist you'll get something like this

```
Warning undefined constant mysqli_assoc assuming 'mysqli_assoc'
```

Answer (score 0):

$row= mysql_fetch_array($ada,mysqli_assoc);

sholud be

$row= mysql_fetch_array($ada,MYSQL_ASSOC);

as MYSQL_ASSOC is a constant